# what is the definition of this phrase?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

A library in Hayward, California is called Weeke branch library

I found out weeke is old spelling of week. by definition of branch I know, I can't see any sense in "weeke branch"
what does "weeke branch" means?

Comment: Weeke is a name, and libraries in American cities have branches in different neighborhoods. There is the main library and there are smaller ones, called branches. So, it's Weeke Branch Library.

Answer (score 1):

What you've found is the [Weekes Branch Library](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Weekes+Branch+Library/@37.633361,-122.081101,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x808f941c153b534f:0x485c99a41cbbcadb!8m2!3d37.633361!4d-122.0789123) in Hayward, California, USA

It's a library branch named after somebody with the family name "Weekes". "Weekes" is a family name.

Here, "branch" is meant in this sense from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/branch):

> **3 c (2) :** a separate but dependent part of a central organization
> *// the neighborhood branch of the city library*